# Laravel, Validate that a field be empty

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

I need that a field be empty when another field be some value. I'm trying to make this:

```
'distance' => 'required_if:distance_type,==,1 | required_without:distance_type,!=,1'
```

The idea behind this is:

If `distance_type` is equal to 1, then `distance` should be required 
AND
If `distance_type` is not equal to 1, then `distance` should be empty, should not have a value.

How could I do it?

Comment: `required_if:distance_type,==,1` is the wrong syntax, just use `required_if:distance_type,1`. Also, `required_without:distance_type,!=,1` is just wrong, you only need `required_without:distance_type`

Comment: Ok with the first one. But I don't get the second one. I need that distance be empty when distance_type be different than 1. Could be 2 or 3

Answer (score 1):

Laravel has a really nice way for managing complex validation logic. You can simply create a rule class, such as `Distance.php` and have the logic in there.

Then for your validator, it would look something like the following:

`'distance' => [new Distance]`

Look at the docs here - https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#custom-validation-rules

Comment: I tried with a closure, but didn't know how to use another attribute inside the validation of another one. I was trying something like: `function($attribute, $value, $fail) {
                    if (here should be distance_type != 1) {
                        return $fail($attribute.' should be empty is distance_type is different than 1);
                    }
                }`

Comment: If you use a class as mentioned above, you can pass the request into the constructor of the rule. This will give you the request so you can access the other attributes of the request

Answer (score 0):

Hi try something like that.

```
return [
        'distance' => 'required_without:distance_type | different: distance_type',
        'distance_type' => 'required_without:distance | different: distance',
    ];
```

Comment: Why "different: distance", I need to filter with a explicit value

Comment: So you could use just first part of rules without different. 
different rule can help if you can send the same values

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
'distance' => 'required_unless:distance_type,2,3,4
```